# How to send voice command to Android device via ADB

Tags: android, automated-tests, adb

I want to invest to test command my application through voice command something like "OK GOOGLE".
In addition to the method of using speakers to speak loudly, how can I say "OK Google" through ADB?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What..! is that even possible? I think not, correct me if I am wrong but using ADB we can't send 'VOICE COMMANDS' to the device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using [Audio Loopback Dongle](https://source.android.com/devices/audio/latency/loopback) for call simulation. Hope it will works for commands too

wav generated by `sudo apt-get install libttspico-utils`

```
pico2wave -w google.wav "OK Google"
```

Move to device

```
adb push google.wav /sdcard/Download/
```

Playing wav by VLC:

```
adb shell am start -n org.videolan.vlc/.StartActivity -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d file:///sdcard/Download/google.wav -t 'audio/wav'
```

Comment: Thank God you are here. I will try it./.